# How to get Log file location in android device?

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat, error-logging

I need android log file in a file format. But i don't Know where is the location of log file. i go through techniques like "adb logcat". but i need the file format of error log. please help me to get the Android Log File. Iam new to this environment please help me.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not stored as a file.

Comment: is there any way to get the log into a file format?

Comment: Use `adb logcat` and redirect the output to a file (e.g., `adb logcat > log.txt`).

Comment: so, as default the device is not storing any logging information in a file format. right?

Comment: Again, AFAIK, the logs are kept only in memory. That is why for a long time they were limited to 64KB, though now in Developer options in Settings you can increase the amount of RAM devoted to the logs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want on PC then what you can do is:-

1) Go to your SDK location >platform-tools

2) Open cmd and type `adb logcat >log.txt` and press enter
It will generate new file `log.txt` there itself.

[image]

If you want to get logs on device you can try [this tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat)